# Maven including a shared jar compiles but not works in real time

Tags: java, maven, jar, shared-libraries, war

I have 2 projects:

ProjectA And SharedProject.

I use the following POM file in ProjectA:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT-1.0.0</version>           
        <scope>compile</scope>          
    </dependency>
<dependency>
```

And the pom of the shared project looks like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>shared</artifactId>
<version>SNAPSHOT-1.0.0</version>
<name>shared</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

My ProjectA compiles (and actually do use imports from SharedProject) so I got that going on for me.

Problem is after running : ProjectA -> mvn install
and running on tomcat
I get an error of:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter cors
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   com.mygroup.shared.filter.common.CorsFilter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This not-found class is located in the SharedProject and referenced in ProjectA web.xml file. here is the ProjectA web.xml specific reference code:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mygroup.shared.filter.common.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Follow the conventions and use a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` cause from Mavens point of view the version `SNAPSHOT-1.0.0` is a release! which will never checked a second time...So the first time you do a `mvn install` the jar will be stored into local cache ok..the second time also but your project which uses it will not being informed that something has changed. That's why you should use so called `SNASPHOT's`...which means a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`....instead...

Answer (score 0):

Remove scope tag from dependency declaration, and everything will be okay.

The scope `compile` says to maven, that this dependency would be used only at the compile time. For example, it used in MapStruct, that generates code at compile phase, and after that there is no need for dependencies.

Comment: The scope compile can be omitted but will not influence the result cause scope `compile` is the default...

Comment: Removing the scope tag from dependency declaration did not help